# Is there is a way to provide edit order option while the order is in Processing in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, order-status, edit, edit-order

Is there is a way to add the edit order option like in pending order in Magento 2.4?

[image]

Like this currently the order status is pending but i want when the order status is processing still need to add the edit order button.

Any link or any idea would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the order status to processing then I think you can edit the or[image]der

Comment: There is no option for edit this order as i have seen in your screenshot.

Comment: In your screen shot there is edit option you can edit

Comment: If the order status is pending it is possible but on processing order status the option is not available.